# Image pixelate on resize browser( responsive design ) after upload on laravel

Tags: laravel, image

After upload the image, on resize browser, or enter the project on the mobile browser, quality of image is very weak, how can i improve that ?

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = $request->name;
            $foldername = $request->name;
            $imagename = $filename .'.' . $request->image->extension();
            $path = public_path('images/produse/'. $filename .'/');

            if(!File::exists($path)){
                File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
            }

            Image::make($image)->resize(200, 200)->save( public_path('images/produse/' . $foldername .  '/' . $imagename ));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with a larger resize resolution. For example (800, 600)

Comment: I tried with the original 1200x1200 picture loaded, it looks pixelated, I made the image from 0 on 200x200, it looks the same, if I take the original picture and put it without uploading, I just add it in the directory, it looks good on mobile